# How do I get Ubuntu to boot when Windows keeps loading instead?

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I have a cheap (but more than adequate) PC I installed Ubuntu on (it is an HP).  Unfortunately, Windows is first in the boot sequence.  The way I am supposed to get Ubuntu up is to hit F7 while starting up.  However, I find that 9 times out of ten Windows insists on coming up, and I don't even use the Windows side.

First, any advice on what might be happening here?  I have just tried 20 times and can't get to my development environment on Ubuntu.

Second, any advice on how to Ubuntu to be the "preferred" OS? Oddly, I have another PC with Windows (from Dell,) which I put Ubuntu on, but rarely use the Ubuntu there.  In that case, when I installed Ubuntu it became the preferred OS, but the BIOS-like screens eventually let me mobe Windows up and Ubuntu down).

Comment: Some with HP have said updating UEFI helped. Many have said efibootmgr to set boot order does not work (or works once). Grub uses efibootmgr to make it first in boot order when you install. Others with HP have said they could reset boot order, but only in UEFI settings & boot tab. Some also have to use hard drive or fallback boot entry. Does a hard drive entry boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Please test the Windows shutdown mode from within Windows by holding down {SHIFT} when you choose Shutdown. Then, do you get a chance to pick Ubuntu? If so, tplease click [edit] and let us know, for you need to make sure your Windows system does not Hibernate or go into Fast Sleep. We can help with that.

Comment: Holding down shift gave no different behavior, powering back up whil holding down F7 went back to Winows